# How to pass parameters in a call to test using quality-center?

Tags: hp-quality-center

Is it possible to pass a parameter of a test case, in the testplan module of hp quality center 10, to a "call to test"? If I add in the call the parameter <<< parameter_name >>> the test runner won't evaluate the parameter to its value.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same ... not just a simple test with parameters, but passing the parameters of a test to sub-tests.

Comment: This just don't work, we updated now to HP QC 11 and this is not a feature of it. If you got Business Process Testing, then you get some more possibilites. But we don't have that license at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. What led me to believe that is was OK is that the 'Used' flag gets updated when you add the parameter to the call to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use triple <<< and >>> signs, have a look at this tutorial video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCrJcHrosio

Comment: I am sorry the html have eaten my third smaller and third bigger sign on this webpage.